# How can I pass a context (in a view, in a field tag) from another field's value?

Tags: openerp-7

I want to create a many2one field which, in view, passes a context:

```
<field name="my_m2o_field" context="{'foo': 'bar'}" />
```

The goal here is to affect the related view (i.e. When you click on "Create and Edit" in a dropdown, you get a popup rendered by the related object's current view).

Such field tag works as expected if, in context, I have something like "{'default_code': 'my.code'}", provided `code` field exists in the related object.

However, the context I actually need is too large (20 entries), and I have to generate 5 contexts like that (with a minor diference, since I have 5 similar fields).

I would like to wrap the context in a -non-storable- functional field (I'd need, actually, 5 similar functional fields), and pass such context as value for the context attribute:

```
<field name="my_context_field" invisible="1" />
<field name="my_m2o_field" context="my_context_field" />
```

Is it possible? What type should I use (type= argument in the `function` constructor).